# "Communication with the SharePoint server is Cancelled" error when building SharePoint hosted addin

Tags: sharepoint

Last month, I had a Sharepoint addin installed into a clients Project Web Access (pwa) server working quite well.

This month, when I try to compile and run a new version of that *same project* in Visual Studio, I'm getting a popup asking "Do you want to switch the project to Offline mode?" and if I say 'No', I get a "Communication with the SharePoint server is Cancelled" error when uploading my project.

There have been no configuration changes. The only code changes were to a .JS file (and we reverted those changes, just in case).

There *may* have been updates to Visual Studio during that time.

I have...

- Ensured that the server name is correct and unchanged.
- Ensured that the 'Server Connection' property for the project is 'Online'

I can't find *any* useful diagnostic information anywhere.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to resolve this, or at least how to get *some* diagnostic information about why it's happening?

Comment: Hmm....I just tried to connect to the system and it looks like there are new Office365 security policy setting that are forbidding Sharepoint Authentication to access Sharepoint (clever, Microsoft).

I've made changes to those policies - hopefully in an hour or so things may change.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Office365/SharePoint Online has new defaults that prevent access from external applications ( I was also unable to connect via PowerShell scripting using my Sharepoint Online credentials).

I updated the settings under **Policies|Access Control** in the Sharepoint Online admin console to allow connection, and now I can connect from PowerShell, and I've got a *different* issue in Visual Studio.

While I still don't have diagnostic information about communication problems, I've managed to get a little further.